# Who is it that killed Zephyr's crew and then became a warlord?

Tags: one-piece

So I just watched the One Piece Movie - The Battle of Z and it left me wondering who it was that killed Zephyr's crew (while he was in the Navy) and then became a warlord? It says he was a devil fruit user and that is why he acquired that weapon on/as his arm to take out all the devil fruit users he could.

Does it get explained anywhere in the manga? Any helpful information would be appreciated!

Comment: It's very probably that is the unnamed warlord since Law now is 26 and 23 years ago he was just 3...so i'd say is impossible to be him, while Buggy was about 16/17 but still i don't think it's him neither...this leaves the option to just the unnamed warlord.

Comment: It's probably Doflamingo. Because as we see now in the new one piece episodes the man is evil as hell.

Comment: haha yeah he is, I despise him. He hurt Law :(

Comment: I can't imagine Buggy actually posing any threat to a marine Admiral, even if he was old enough

Comment: It would make sense if it was Doflamingo because he is one of the Celestial Dragons(I think), which would explain why his crimes would be excused.

Comment: I hate to say this... but isnt it bazaar that the pirate who killed his family became a warlord... now, look at Zeds flag roger... the sword stabbing the inverted navy logo looks awfully like Mihawks Black Sword... but see.. mihawk isnt shown to have DF powers... i know it doesnt add up... i just find it weird that Mihawk, the warlord... his sword is the same sword on the jolly roger of Zed

Answer (score 4):

The Warlord who killed Zephyr's crew is not named even in the current chapter of the manga.

Nevertheless, it was stated that the pirate who killed Zephyr's crew became a warlord during the timeskip. Therefore, there are only three possibilities: **Trafalgar Law**, **Buggy** and the currently **unnamed warlord**. However, it it also not yet revealed whether the unnamed warlord is a devil fruit user.

Comment: Are you sure it was during the time skip? There is no way he would get that old in just a few years....He was much younger when his crew was killed, at least it looked like there was no way it was doable in the time skip. Add a source and I'll buy it :p

Comment: What I said is that the pirate who killed his crew became a warlord during the timeskip. You can read it on his history here: http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Zephyr . =)

Answer (score 0):

That pirate who killed Zephyr's crew is not Law, Buggy, Doflamingo or any of the current warlords. First, you must consider Zephyr's age. I think it was 20 years ago when the accident happened to his crew; then, that pirate became a warlord. So it's not during the 2-year timeskip. Also, the film Z movie is non-canon, meaning it is just a filler and not related to the real story.

Comment: But consider that Oda usually has at least some minor input on non-canon to make sure they don't use things he wants to later.  Foreshadowing canon inforamtion in a non-canon movie is, therefore, still possible.

Answer (score -1):

I'm pretty certain it was either Doflamanco, Jimbei, or Crocodile because all the warlords at the time who could have done it would either not have or they wouldn't have used a cutting weapon. Kuma wouldn't have because he was a double agent for Dragon and he is trying to keep his cover. Boa didn't because they would've been turned to stone not murdered. The zombie guy who is dead now would've abducted the dead crew. Mihawk who does use a cutting weapon wouldn't have because he seems to obey orders without much argument. Buggy and trafalgar weren't warlords at the time.

Comment: It can't be either one of them; As it was stated in the movie, the pîrate who cut off Z's arm only became a Warlord during the timeskip, which rules out any of the original seven as well as Blackbeard.